# Tumblr API posting to secondary blog

Tags: python, python-3.x, tumblr

I am trying to use Tumblr API to post something to my secondary blog. I am using [Tumblpy](https://github.com/michaelhelmick/python-tumblpy) Python package because [official Tumblr client](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr) is for Python 2 only and it seems abandoned anyway.

I authorized the app and I took a look at [Tumblr console](https://api.tumblr.com/console/calls/user/info) where I picked up all the keys from. I started to play around with it and I have noticed that I can successfully post to my primary blog, but not on secondary (getting `{TumblpyError} 404 'There was an error making your request.'` error all the time).

This is the code I've been trying out:

```
from tumblpy import Tumblpy


def post_tumblr(
        url,
        comment='',
        tags='',
        **kwargs
):
    t = Tumblpy(
        APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,
        OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
    )

    blog_url = t.post('user/info')
    blog_url = blog_url['user']['blogs'][0]['url']  # POSTING TO PRIMARY BLOG WORKS
    # blog_url = blog_url['user']['blogs'][1]['url']  # CANNOT POST TO SECONDARY BLOG?

    post_url = t.post(
        'post',
        blog_url=blog_url,
        params={
            'type': 'video',
            'embed': url,
            'caption': comment,
            'tags': tags,
        }
    )

    return True
```

Is there some catch in posting to secondary blog in Tumblr API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting one. The first thing to note is that in the Tumblr API, any `blog.url` is a full url, including the scheme: `http://` or `https://`. However, in any `/blog/{blog-identifier}/*` API request, it *does not* accept a full url, only the hostname: `example.com` or `demo.tumblr.com`.

Given this information, it seems like *neither* of your requests should work, so I checked out the code for Tumblpy a bit. It turns out that Tumblpy does accept a full url for a `{blog-identifier}`, by stripping away everything except the hostname. However, it only works with `http://` urls, and not `https://` urls, as seen [here](https://github.com/michaelhelmick/python-tumblpy/blob/master/tumblpy/api.py#L112).

If you have a blog with SSL enabled, the `url` field will be an `https://` link, and then Tumblpy will not handle it correctly. I'm assuming this is the case for your secondary blog; you can check on your [settings page](https://www.tumblr.com/settings) for that blog.

Assuming this is the case, the best fix will be to just construct the hostname yourself before calling `Tumblpy.post()`. Just use `user.blogs[i].name + ".tumblr.com"`. Or, you can parse the hostname from the url too. Either approach will work.